# Weird character 'q' problem with DataGridView Custom DataGridViewColumn cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I've created a custom column for the datagridview deriving it from DataGridViewColumn, DataGridViewTextBoxCell and implementing the IDataGridViewEditingControl.

I've created a user control which contains a simple TextBox and I used this control as editing control for that column.

Now I'm getting a weird problem with this scenario. When I press character 'q', the cell in the custom column of DataGridView doesn't display it and nothing happens, but when I press any other key it properly displays in the cell.

What could be the issue here? I tried all kind of ways by debugging it for every event but in vain I couldn't find anything yet.

I'm giving the code below of custom column I created.

```
  public class CustomControlColumn : DataGridViewColumn
  {
    public CustomControlColumn() : base(new CustomTextCell()) { }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
      get
      {
        return base.CellTemplate;
      }
      set
      {
        // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CustomComboCell.
        if (value != null && !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CustomTextCell)))
        {
          throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CustomTextCell");
        }

        base.CellTemplate = value;
      }
    }
  }

  public class CustomTextCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
  {
    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
      // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
      base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
      var control = DataGridView.EditingControl as CustomTextBoxControl;

      if (OwningColumn == null)
        return;

      // Use the default row value when Value property is null.
      if (Value == null)
      {
        control.Text = string.Empty;
      }
      else
      {
        control.Text = Value.ToString();
      }
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
      get
      {
        // Return the type of the editing contol that CustomComboCell uses.
        return typeof(CustomControlEditingControl);
      }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
      get
      {
        // Return the type of the value that CustomTextCell contains.
        return typeof(String);
      }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
      get
      {
        // Use the empty string as the default value.
        return string.Empty;
      }
    }
  }

  class CustomControlEditingControl : CustomTextBoxControl, IDataGridViewEditingControl
  {
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
      // Nothing to do
    }

    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
      // Let the control handle the keys listed.
      switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
      {
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Right:
        case Keys.Home:
        case Keys.End:
        case Keys.PageDown:
        case Keys.PageUp:
          return true;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    }

    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
      return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView { get; set; }

    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
      get { return Text; }
      set { Text = value.ToString(); }
    }

    public int EditingControlRowIndex { get; set;}

    public bool EditingControlValueChanged { get; set; }

    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
      get { return base.Cursor; }
    }

    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
      get { return false; }
    }
  }
```

I've added this as one of the column in my DataGridView through designer and DataGridView is not associated with any DataSource.

Can anybody point me towards the problem in this code?

Comment: does the "q" ever show up in the box...or only if you press it FIRST?

Comment: @curtisk: It never show up, when I copy it from somewhere and paste it gets displayed. Also if I press Shift+q it gets displayed as capital 'Q'. I'm very much surprised with this behaviour.

Comment: It is not just 'q' key. If I use the arrow keys to navigate to the cell and press a key, that key input is ignored. Otherwise it works fine.. takes 'q' and other key inputs.

Comment: @Vijay: Did q key works for you? Strange, I tried it with two sample winforms application and this key never worked. Only captial Q worked.

Comment: That's a lot of code to sift through. Any chance you could narrow it down for us?

Comment: @Justin: Sorry for the long code post. I posted complete custom column code, so that I dont miss any point. I cant remove any code from it as that will not work if somebody wants to create a custom column with above code. Or if one knows how to create custom column, then they dont have to go through it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the below change and see if that helps:

```
public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
      // Let the control handle the keys listed.
      switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
      {
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Right:
        case Keys.Home:
        case Keys.End:
        case Keys.PageDown:
        case Keys.PageUp:
          return true;
        default:
         // return false; <--not this
         return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey; //try this!
      }
    }
```

Comment: That's perfect curtisk. That was bulls eye. I read the explanation given by Vijay Sirigiri too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Very weird and inconsistent, even if you look in MSDN the code samples vary from 2.0 -> 4.0, glad I(we) were able to find this odd answer

Comment: Seriously very weird, I was trying to find the reason behind it since last 4 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put this code and see the behavior. (see my comments below your question)

The problem you stated.. I could repro by using the arrow keys -> navigating to the cell.
The issue is it goes to edit mode only after a first key is pressed.
Try to put this code in CustomTextCell type and see the behavior.

```
 public override bool KeyEntersEditMode(KeyEventArgs e)
 {
     // for testing..     
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. In my app, DGV is already having EditOnEnter property to true. So, when I click on that cell it enters into edit mode and if I press any other key it displays, but q is not displayed whether it is first key I'm pressing or after some keys. Completely baffled with this behavior. Are you able to get the q key displayed even after entering some other chars?

Comment: Yes. But as I mentioned it happens for the first time with any keystroke. I'll try to set the property and see what happens. But after adding the code I posted, it works fine.

Comment: 'q' character never show up in my sample app. But if I use shift+q then it show up even for the first key press. :(

Comment: http://www.windowsdevelop.com/windows-forms-data-controls-databinding/lower-case-q-keystroke-doesnt-work-inside-a-custom-cell-of-data-grid-view-control-37106.shtml  -- Read the explanation... in EditingControlWantsInputKey method - return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey for default case.

Comment: Thanks Vijay for helping me out. I read the explanation. curtisk answer worked for me and then I read this link.